# Loading footer while loading a list view

Tags: android, listview, indexoutofboundsexception, onscroll

I have a list view which has onscroll listener to load more items. When more items are loading a listvview footer would be displayed. When I run the app the first items of list are loaded and when scrolling to the end to load more items the app crashes.

My code

```
public class InterActivity extends Activity 
{


ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
FinalAdapter adapter;
 List<CodeList> codelist = null;
 SharedPreference shrdPreference;

 private int limit = 15;


View footerView;






@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inter_layout);
    shrdPreference = new SharedPreference();


    //Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(InterActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait loading ...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
            query.setLimit(limit);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {


                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));
                map.setFinalCodeText((String) inter.get("codetext"));


                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inter_layoutListView);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this,
                                      codelist);

    //  AlphaInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
    //  animationAdapter.setAbsListView(listview);




        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        //listview.setOnItemClickListener(InterActivity.this);

        //listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(InterActivity.this); 
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

//          setup onscrll listener

```
        listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                                                 int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int threshold = 1;
                    int count = listview.getCount();

                    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                            - threshold) {
                            // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
                            new Loadmore().execute();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });




    }
}


private class Loadmore extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.loadmore, null, false); 
        listview.addFooterView(footerView);

        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        codelist.clear();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
            query.setLimit(limit += 15);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {


                map.setFinalCodeText((String) inter.get("codetext"));


                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        int position = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();



    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.removeFooterView(footerView);

listview.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

**my logcat**

01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.enlightenme.pac, PID: 12753
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 1
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:225)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1356)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1651)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Posted my complete log. Please have a look

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index ... so check your array size related code

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way also

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                // your load more code
                return true;
            }
        });
```

create EndlessScrollListener.java

```
import android.widget.AbsListView; 

public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
        this.currentPage = startPage;
    }

    // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
    // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
    // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
        {
        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; } 
        }
        // If it's still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }

        // If it isn't currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            loading = onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    // Returns true if more data is being loaded; returns false if there is no more data to load.
    public abstract boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Don't take any action on changed
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried with your code bro still crashes. Getting this exception  in logcat IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131099667, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]

Comment: that means you are setting data from adapter in background thread. don't set data in list from background. set data using Ui thread.

Comment: Yeah will try as you said